# How to mirror a repo, and merge changes from source into target

Tags: git

I have a question regarding `git clone -mirror`.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a (source) Repo A that I have mirrored to (target) Repo B.

```
> git clone --mirror https://github.com/sourceRepo.git
> cd sourceRepo.git # Go into the mirror source.
> git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/targetRepo.git
```

I want to be able to create new content on targetRepo, and also merge content from sourceRepo into the targetRepo.

As an example:

**After Mirror**

```
sourceRepo: fileA, fileB, dirA/, dirB/, dirC/
targetRepo: fileA, fileB, dirA/, dirB/, dirC/
```

Create new directory `dirD` in sourceRepo, and new directory `dirE` in targetRepo.

```
Push the new changes from sourceRepo to targetRepo.
```

**End result**

```
sourceRepo: fileA, fileB, dirA/, dirB/, dirC/, dirD/
targetRepo: fileA, fileB, dirA/, dirB/, dirC/, dirD/, dirE/
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Just use `git clone`, no mirror?

Comment: A mirror clone is a repository copy in which you promise you will never do any work. A non-mirror clone is a repository copy in which you *will* do work. If you want to do work, make a non-mirror clone.

Comment: Essentially, I want to know how I can to a 1:N push.  Make a change in my 1 source repo, and PUSH this change to all my N target repos.  Assume only master branches (no private branches).

Answer (score 0):

> Create new directory dirD in sourceRepo,

That suggests sourceRepo (cloned) has a working tree.
But a clone --mirror would create a *bare* repository (no working tree)

So, as commented, don't use `--mirror`.
Adding `set-url --push` is one correct approach to push to multiple remote URL with one command.